# How to communicate Queue output between different files

Tags: python, websocket

I have two websocket endpoints and both are in separate files mouse.py and video.py, in mouse.py, I start the MouseProcessor module imported from mouseProcessor.py which put mouse data inside the queue, here is the code from mouse.py :-

```py
from processing.mouse_processor import MouseProcessor
async def handle_mouse(websocket: WebSocket, token: str = Query(...), authorize: AuthJWT = Depends()):
    await manager.connect(websocket)
    print(f"{datetime.utcnow()}: Client connected: {websocket.client.host}")

    process_manager = Manager()

    input_queue = process_manager.Queue()
    lock = process_manager.Lock()

    processor = MouseProcessor(input_queue=input_queue,
                          lock=lock)
    processor.start()
    mouseList = []

    try:
        while True:
            data = await websocket.receive_json()
            if data:
                print(data) 
                coordinates = [data["x"], data["y"]]
                #mouseList.append(coordinates)
                input_queue.put(coordinates)

    except WebSocketDisconnect:
        print(f"Client disconnected: {websocket.client.host}")
        manager.disconnect(websocket)
        processor.shutdown()
```

And this is the code for MouseProcessor.py

```py
import os
from multiprocessing import Queue, Process
from multiprocessing.synchronize import Lock



class MouseProcessor(Process):
    input_queue = Queue()
    lock: Lock

    def __init__(self, input_queue: Queue, lock: Lock):
        super(MouseProcessor, self).__init__()
        self.input_queue = input_queue
        self.lock = lock

    def output(self):
        print(f"Draining input queue with {self.input_queue.qsize()} mouse..")
        mouseCoordinateList = []

        while not self.input_queue.empty():
            mouseCoordinateSelf = self.input_queue.get()
            #mouseCoordinate = mouseCoordinateSelf.get_image()
            mouseCoordinateList.append(mouseCoordinateSelf)
        print(mouseCoordinateList)
        print(len(mouseCoordinateList))

    def shutdown(self):
        print("Shutting down processor..")
        if self.input_queue.empty():
            print("Processor queue is empty, terminating..")
        else:
            print("Processor queue is not empty, saving remaining mouse..")
            self.output()
        self.terminate()
```

When I call the processor.shutdown() function inside the mouse.py where I put the values, it works fine, it prints the values, but now instead of output the values in the mouse.py, I want to output the values in video.py file, here is my video.py :-

```py
async def handle_video(websocket: WebSocket, token: str = Query(...), authorize: AuthJWT = Depends()):
    await manager.connect(websocket)
    print(f"{datetime.utcnow()}: Client connected: {websocket.client.host}")

   
    
    try:
        while True:
            print('hello')
    except WebSocketDisconnect:
        print(f"Client disconnected: {websocket.client.host}")
        manager.disconnect(websocket)
```